# __rtruediv__ method does not work as I expect

Tags: python

Using Python 3, I create:

```
class NewInt(int):
  def __rtruediv__(self, num):
    print('in here')

x = NewInt(5)

343 / x    # called rtruediv as I expect, but

343.3 / x  # does not call rtruediv
```

Not sure why this is because:

```
x / 343
x / 343.3   #both will call truediv
```

To me, this seems inconsistent.

Does anyone have an explanation of why this is, and when Python does `343.3 / x` is there a method that can be overridden?

Answer (score 6):

In short, the left operand gets the first shot at handling the operation, except under some special circumstances.

The relevant documentation here is in [emulating numeric types](https://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types):

> **Note:** If the right operand's type is a subclass of the left operand's type and that subclass provides the reflected method for the operation, this method will be called before the left operand's non-reflected method. This behavior allows subclasses to override their ancestors' operations.

So in the case of:

```
343.3 / x  # does not call __rtruediv__
```

The left hand wins because `float` division by `int` is defined, and `NewInt` [is a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a)n `int`.  That is, `343.3.__truediv__(x)` succeeds without error.

Let's reconcile all four cases in light of the documentation to see that there is not really any inconsistent behaviour here:

```
343 / x     # x.__rtruediv__ wins because NewInt subclasses int
343.3 / x   # 343.3.__truediv__ wins because NewInt doesn't subclass float
x / 343     # x.__truediv__ wins because int doesn't subclass NewInt
x / 343.3   # x.__truediv__ wins because float doesn't subclass NewInt
```

Comment: ahh.. both this and the one below are great answers. I had no idea of the actual details in how Python handles objects on the right side of an operator. It is not quite how I expected, and I can now see it needs to be this way. There is, in fact, then, no way to over-ride the operation of: 343.3/x using any new method in NewInt because it is using the truediv method of the float object. Over-riding operators becomes more complex than one might first think.. Some texts seems to leave out this 'detail'

Comment: That is not quite correct.  It is possible, if `NewInt` is changed not to inherit `int` (or any other class that float knows how to divide by).  In this case, the left-hand-side attempt will fail, however the right-hand-side now gets a shot.  Then, assuming you have implemented `__rtruediv__` correctly, the result from the right operand's division method will be returned without any error.

Answer (score 5):

`__rtruediv__` only has priority over `__truediv__` if the right-hand operand is an instance of a subclass of the left-hand operand's class.

When you do `343 / x`, `NewInt` is a subclass of `int`, so x's `__rtruediv__` gets priority. When you do `343.3 / x`, `NewInt` is not a subclass of `float`, so 343.3's `__truediv__` gets priority.

`343.3.__truediv__(x)` doesn't return `NotImplemented`, since `float` knows how to divide a float by an int. Thus, `x.__rtruediv__` doesn't get called.