# How does pathlib.Path implement '/' when the left operand is a string?

Tags: python, pathlib

I understand how `__truediv__` works, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53085465/21115).

But in this case:

```
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> 'foo' / Path('bar')
PosixPath('foo/bar')
```

Surely `__truediv__` is called on `str`, because `'foo'` is the left operand to `/`, in that case how can it return a `Path`?

Comment: Because strings say "I don't implement that" and Path's implementation is next up. It's only a type error if _neither_ operand supports it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53083963/python-pathlib-operator-how-does-it-do-it/53085465#comment125664547_53085465, https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rtruediv__, https://stackoverflow.com/q/37310077/3001761

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a toy path – call it a ploth. It implements `__rtruediv__` and `__truediv__`, so you can use it for division either way around. Since `str` does not implement either `__rtruediv__` or `__truediv__`, `Ploth` gets to do that. (I'm only deriving from `str` to get a convenient constructor and `__repr__()`.)

```
class Ploth(str):
    def __rtruediv__(self, other):
        print(f"__rtruediv__({self!r}, {other!r})")
        return f"{other!r} / {self!r}"

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        print(f"__truediv__({self!r}, {other!r})")
        return f"{self!r} / {other!r}"


print("plar" / Ploth("ploth"))
print(Ploth("ploth") / "plar")
```

This prints out:

```
__rtruediv__('ploth', 'plar')
'plar' / 'ploth'
__truediv__('ploth', 'plar')
'ploth' / 'plar'
```

From Python's [docs on `__rtruediv__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__rtruediv__#object.__rtruediv__):

> These methods are called to implement the binary arithmetic operations
> (`+`, `-`, `*`, `@`, `/`, `//`, `%`, `divmod()`, `pow()`, `**`, `<<`,
> `>>`, `&`, `^`, `|`) with reflected (swapped) operands. These
> functions are only called if the left operand does not support the
> corresponding operation and the operands are of different types.